# Can a dryad charm a demon?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

I have a concept that I want to use of a dryad soothing a demon, which shall be a demon's past as their first step to redemption. So is there any way a demon/fiend be charmed by a dryad, if this could happen in the rules. If not is there a way to get around that problem? The fiend is a yochlol, which can't return to their original plane, and is having an angry fit about it in a forest and destroying the forest with what they touch.

Comment: Are you specifically asking about the Yochlol or do you want a more general answer?

Comment: And are you asking about the Dryad's Fey Charm or if they can just cast a *charm X* spell on them?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Pre-empting your response to NautArch's question, I've assumed you're talking about Fey Charm, which isn't a spell but a monster feature, and have therefore replaced the [spells] tag with the [monsters] tag (a catch-all tag for monster abilities like Fey Charm, etc). If I have assumed wrong, you can [edit] your question to undo my changes.

Answer (score 18):

## According to the written rules, no.

A dryad's Fey Charm action specifically says it

> targets one humanoid or beast that she can see within 30 feet of her.

A yochlol is a fiend (and a demon and a shapechanger), not a humanoid or a beast, so it can't be targeted by the dryad's Fey Charm.

### Practically, however, you can do whatever you want to make a good story.

If you are the DM you can adjust the rules or just make the rules obey your story structure. The important thing is having a good time, not maintaining 100% fidelity to the rules as written. If that means that this yochol gets charmed by this dryad, just make it happen and don't worry about it.